# pass parameters in insert query stored procedure in laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, insert, laravel

I have created a procedure for insertion but dont know how to call parameters "name" and "path" in controller and model

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
     PROCEDURE `insert_document_details`
        (IN `name` VARCHAR(50), IN `path` VARCHAR(255) )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `document_details`
      (`document_name`, `document_path`) 
    VALUES (name,path);
END
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('insert_document_details/{name}/{path}',array('as'=>'insert_document_details',
'uses'=>'AuthorsController@post_document_details'));
```

AuthorController:

```
class AuthorsController extends BaseController{
        public $restful = true;

        public function post_document_details($name,$path)
        {

            $document_details=Response::json(Author::insert_document_details_Call());
            return $document_details;
        }
}
```

Author(model):

```
class Author extends Eloquent {

    public $table = 'document_details';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public static function insert_document_details_Call($name,$path)
    {
        return DB::select('call insert_document_details');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second takes a list of parameters that can be passed as below

```
DB::select('call insert_document_details(?,?)',array($name,$path));
```

or

```
DB::statement('call insert_document_details(' . DB::raw($name) . ',' . DB::raw($path) . ')');
```