# Using a stored procedure in Laravel 4

Tags: stored-procedures, laravel-4

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from via a laravel route and i keep getting an error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'emailAddress' in 'field list' (SQL: CALL getLibraryList(emailAddress))",
```

I believe the call I'm making is correct:

```
$result = DB::statement('CALL getLibraryList('.$email.')');
return $result;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found out a way to get this working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102537/pass-parameters-in-insert-query-stored-procedure-in-laravel-4):

```
$result = DB::select('call getLibraryList(?)',array($email));
```

Comment: This isn't completely valid since you do not retrieve a specific class, you get an stdClass object.

Comment: What if i i have 3 other out parameters also then what should i do

Comment: Alternative is : $result = DB::select(DB::raw("CALL retrieve_bill_home(:user_id)"), array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id
        ));

Comment: @gin93r Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838922/how-can-i-convert-many-statement-mysql-to-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 3):

You might find some trouble to execute them. Here are some options:

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('CALL getLibraryList('.$email.');'));
```

Or

```
DB::select('CALL getLibraryList(?)',array($email));
```

And, the dirtiest one:

```
$db = DB::connection();

$stmt = $db->pdo->prepare("CALL getLibraryList(?)");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $email);
$stmt->execute();

$search = array();

do {
    $search = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'stdClass');
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());
```

Comment: Results in the same. I actually tried that before - though I didn't have the semicolon before. Still - same results.

Comment: Thanks for the Help @Antonio I found an answer. :)

Comment: @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838922/how-can-i-convert-many-statement-mysql-to-laravel-eloquent