# SQL query left joining issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have two tables: `users` and `userlogs`

```
table1
----------
id | name
----------
1 | A
2 | B
3 | C
4 | D


table2
----------
user_id | date
----------
1 | 2015-12-17
2 | 2015-12-18
3 | 2015-12-19
4 | 2015-12-20
```

If I do LEFT JOIN with selected date, it only gives data that exist in table 2.

```
SELECT r.user_id, count(r.user_id) as count
FROM table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 r ON ( r.user_id = a.id )
WHERE r.created_at BETWEEN '2015-12-17' AND '2015-12-19'
GROUP BY a.id
```

I get the following

```
Result
----------
user_id | count
----------
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 1
```

I need something like the following:

```
Result
----------
user_id | count
----------
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 1
4 | 0
```

I have tried many different ways, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved. Some of them have a odd group by behavior...)

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, move the right side table conditions from WHERE to ON clause to get true left join result. (Else it behaves as a regular inner join.)

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should do just fine:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
(
    id INT
    , name VARCHAR(50)
);

DECLARE @T2 TABLE
(
    [user_id] INT
    , [date] DATE
);

INSERT INTO @T1 (id, name)
VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D');

INSERT INTO @T2 ([user_id], [date])
VALUES (1, '2015-12-17'), (2, '2015-12-18'), (3, '2015-12-19'), (4, '2015-12-20');

SELECT T1.id, COALESCE(T2.Cnt, 0) AS Cnt
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM @T1) AS T1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [user_id], COUNT(*) AS Cnt
    FROM @T2
    WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2015-12-17' AND '2015-12-19'
    GROUP BY [user_id]
    ) AS T2
    ON T2.[user_id] = t1.id;
```

It outputs what you are expecting :)

Or wrap it up a in a stored procedure like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProcedure
(
    @company_id INT
    , @start_date DATE
    , @end_date DATE
)
as
SELECT T1.id
    , T1.department_id
    , COALESCE(T2.cnt, 0) AS cnt
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT id, department_id
    FROM users
    WHERE company_id = @company_id
    ) AS T1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM userlogs
    WHERE created_at BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
    GROUP BY user_id
    ) AS T2
    ON T2.user_id = t1.id;
```

And just call it by passing variables to it. [Using a stored procedure in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517903/using-a-stored-procedure-in-laravel-4) explains how to do it.

Comment: Your query doesn't seem to be efficient, why creating temp tables?

Comment: would it be possible to make it simple?

Comment: @user4499992 I'm creating temporary tables just for test data you've given us. Use your tables instead of `@T1` and `@T2`

Comment: SELECT T1.id, T1.department_id, COALESCE(T2.cnt, 0) AS cnt FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, department_id FROM users WHERE company_id = '33') AS T1 LEFT JOIN ( SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM userlogs WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2015-12-17' AND '2016-01-12' GROUP BY user_id ) AS T2 ON T2.user_id = t1.id

Comment: can we make it simpel

Comment: Well, it's simple enough.

Comment: I am working with laravel and converting to Eloquent is very difficult

Comment: SELECT T1.id, T1.department_id, COALESCE(T2.cnt, 0) AS cnt FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, department_id FROM users WHERE company_id = '33') AS T1 LEFT JOIN ( SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM userlogs WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2015-12-17' AND '2016-01-12' GROUP BY user_id ) AS T2 ON T2.user_id = t1.id

Comment: You should've mentioned this in your question before asking. You asked for a RAW SQL Query.

Comment: I know and thought it would be simple when joining two tables

Comment: Why not to wrap it up in a stored procedure with parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the filter condition into the left join.

```
SELECT 
   a.id, 
   count(r.user_id) as count
FROM table1 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 r ON r.user_id = a.id AND 
                            r.created_at BETWEEN '2015-12-17' AND '2015-12-19'
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but its not working. it gives NULL

Comment: I just set up the test tables as you described (assuming that you mean to have a column called created_at rather than called date) and it works for me

Answer (score 1):

If your filtered column in WHERE clause specified with LEFT OUTER JOIN then the Join behave exactly same as INNER JOIN. If you do not wish to change the behaviour of LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN then go for ON & AND condition.

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.USER_ID
    WHERE T2.DATE BETWEEN '2015-12-17' AND '2015-12-19'
```

Is same as below

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.USER_ID
    WHERE T2.DATE BETWEEN '2015-12-17' AND '2015-12-19'
```

In your case you need to go for

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.USER_ID 
    AND T2.DATE BETWEEN '2015-12-17' AND '2015-12-19'
```