# laravel sql server stored procedure output

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I have already created a SQL Store Produced like this:

```
USE [xxx]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ResultsByRegionAndDate]    Script Date: 02/25/2016 14:29:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ResultsByRegionAndDate]
    @Region VARCHAR(10),
    @DayD DATETIME,
    @DaySpin DATETIME OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    /* logic here */
END
```

And now, in my Laravel project, althought I've tried many way to get output on stored produce but still fail.

```
$region = 'BAC';
$ngay = '2016-02-25';

$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('DECLARE @DaySpin datetime EXEC dbo.ResultsByRegionAndDate ?, ?, @DaySpin');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $region);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $ngay);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $out);
$stmt->execute();
$search = array();
do {
    $search = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());

return $out; // to see the result
```

When code is running, `$out` is empty, I don't know how to get output from stored product.

Are there any way to get output without modify stored produce?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours of working, I've found the solutions for this case, if anyone has same problem like me might use this to resolve it.

Problem here is I was wrong about the way of reading output param, here is the right way.

```
$out = '';
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('DECLARE @NgayQuay datetime; EXEC dbo.ResultsByRegionAndDate ?,?, @NgayQuay OUTPUT');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $region);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $ngay);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bindColumn(3, $out);
$x = $stmt->fetchAll();

return $out; //that's output
```

Working key is `$stmt->bindColumn(3, $out);` hope this help someone.

Happy coding.

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838922/how-can-i-convert-many-statement-mysql-to-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`$stmt = $pdo->prepare('DECLARE @DaySpin datetime EXEC dbo.ResultsByRegionAndDate ?, ?, @DaySpin OUTPUT');`

If you want sql to return a value to an output parameter you have to specify OUTPUT at the end of the parameter.

Comment: I do that too but I don't know how to get `@DaySpin` value

Comment: I really can't help you with laravel, I was poiting out the SQL mistake. Maybe look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517903/using-a-stored-procedure-in-laravel-4 ?

Comment: Thanks for what you have done for me, I've found the solutions for this problem.